# PHP method mock check for an argument passed to the method

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I am using the Phpunit for unit testing and its mocking framework. I have a mock for a method:

```
    $myProcessor
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method("myMockedMethodName");
```

I would like to validate one of the arguments passed to it.

For example, my function takes arg1, arg2, arg3. I would like to check only for the arg2.

How to do with PHP mocks?

Comment: Using `->with()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use the `with()` method as explained in the docs (https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test-doubles.html#test-doubles-mock-objects-examples-subjecttest2-php)

Comment: Updated the question, 

For example, my myMockedMethod takes arg1, arg2 and arg3. I would like to check only for the arg2. How to do that?

Comment: >with($this->anything(), $this->equalTo("some-value"));

worked for me.